# Gridless Pathfinding - Unity3D

Tags: c#, algorithm, unity-game-engine, path-finding

I was wondering what best approach to take when trying to implement pathfinding but without using a grid.

In this example, the player is a able to place road tiles on a grid, but I only want to pathfind the placed roads (no need to compute for the whole map).

I've tried a couple things but with no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for A* algorithm. There are also other ways to do this, but most of them are based on graphs, including [Unity NavMesh](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Navigation.html).

There is amazing site with interactive examples and implementation guide, for sure it will be helpful, whether you want to implement this yourself or just understand how it works:
https://www.redblobgames.com/pathfinding/a-star/introduction.html

Comment: Thanks Griva, that link was super helpful.